# How to validate k-means result

Tags: machine-learning, k-means, validation, large-data, unsupervised-learning

I'm doing anomaly detection on unsupervised data using k-means I got a result but I don't know how to validate my clustering result.
by plotting I can see my anomalies but how should I validate that clustering is accurate.
in supervised learning, we use cross-validation like this any method or technique for unsupervised means.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use any CV method for this, as you should know the expected result for your training / validating data. Supervised just means the algorithm knows what the answer should be, and unsupervised it doesn't. 
If you don't know what the answer should be then you have no way of telling if it is right or wrong yourself